# How to write a stored procedure using functions?

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

Hi all I am new to functions so am having a bit starting trouble here

I have two tables like this

**Bugs**

```
BugID|Title|ProjectName|CreatedBy
```

**BugHistory**

```
BughistoryID|BugID|Assignedto|ToStatus|FromStatus
```

I want to write an insert stored procedure for the `Bugs` table where I will insert `[Title]|[ProjectName]` and `[CreatedBy]` into the `bugs` table and `BugID` has Identity and primary key.

After that, I have to insert the `BugID` of the new title and `Tostatus` into the `BugHistory` table. These two steps should be done in a single stored procedure.

I want a select statement where I have to show the bugs table in gridview with `[AssignedTo]` and `[Tostatus]` columns from `BugHistory` table. How can I use functions for this both procedure s any ideas please?

Comment: @Ic i tried a store procedure for InsertLogic using joins but it didn't work because of the foreignkey constraint....

Comment: using `Identity` as foreign key is not recommended. However try solution from [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=108333)

Comment: it's a **STORED** procedure, *stored* inside your SQL Server (has nothing to do with a "store")

Comment: @bjan: I don't think the foreign key (`BugID`) is an identity column in the `BugHistory` table - but it **references** the identity column `BugID` in the `Bugs` table - and that's a totally valid, actually a **recommended** approach for sure!

Comment: @marc_s I think there is some !@#$%^&, here is what i got. `BugID` is the primary key of `Bugs` table and it is an `Identity` column which is then passed to `BugHistory` table as foreign key (OP posted a comment stating `foreignkey constraint`). To me, it looks an identity column is being used as foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
-- create stored procedure to insert a new bug, with parameters
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertBug 
    @Title VARCHAR(100),
    @ProjectName VARCHAR(100),
    @CreatedBy VARCHAR(100)
AS BEGIN

  -- variable to hold newly inserted "BugID"    
  DECLARE @NewBugID INT

  -- do the insert into the "Bugs" table      
  INSERT INTO dbo.Bugs(Title, ProjectName, CreatedBy)
  VALUES(@Title, @ProjectName, @CreatedBy)

  -- get the new BugID that's been assigned during INSERT      
  SELECT @NewBugID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  -- insert into the BugHistory table - since you didn't specify anything,
  -- I assumed the bug gets assigned to whoever created it by default,
  -- and I assumed "ToStatus" is a string column so I assigned "New" to it
  -- ADAPT as needed !
  INSERT INTO dbo.BUgHistory(BugID, AssignedTo, ToStatus)
  VALUES(@NewBugID, @CreatedBy, 'New')
END
```

Comment: just to clear myself, though i have tested `SCOPE_IDENTITY` with four different executions and it worked fine, what if another insert statement is executed in between `INSERT INTO dbo.Bugs(...` and `SELECT @NewBugID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, would SCOPE_IDENTITY() return the correct value? could there be any problem with so many parallel executions of this procedure??

Comment: @bjan: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last `IDENTITY` value inserted in that scope. So if you have another INSERT before you check for `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, it depends on whether that insert also goes into a table with an IDENTITY column - if so, you'll get *that* IDENTITY value back. Use SCOPE_IDENTITY *right after* the INSERT you're interested in, and you should be fine.

Comment: @marc_s what should i do for my select statement

Answer (score 0):

try creating a trigger in your Bugs to insert data in you BugsHistory AFTER INSERT